# Counting words occurrence in a string

Tags: c, algorithm, count

I'm trying to count words occurrence in a string. For a string S, I need to show each word and how many times this word is present in the string.

Exemple:

```
string = ";! one two, tree foor one two !:;"
```

Result:

```
one: 2
two: 2
tree: 1
foor: 1
```

Here is my code but it's not returning the right count:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int count_word(char * mot, char * text) {
  int n = 0;
  char *p;

  p = strstr(text, mot);

  while (p != NULL) {
    n++;
    p = strstr(p + 1, mot);
  }  

  return n;
}

void show_all_words(char * text) {
    char * p = strtok(text, " .,;-!?");

    while (p != NULL) {
      printf ("%s : %d\n", p, count_word(p, text));
      p = strtok(NULL, " .,;-!?");
    }
}

int main(char *argv[]) {

    char text[] = ";! one two, tree foor one two !:;";
    show_all_words(&text);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
};
```

it's returning:

```
one : 1
two : 0
tree : 0
foor : 0
one : 1
two : 0
: : 0
```

Comment: Are you asking a C question or a C++ question? They are different languages, and the tags cannot be used interchangeably.

Comment: I fixed that and removed the c++ tag, I'm asking a C question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `strtok` changes its parameter. You can fix the problem by duplicating the string, calling `strtok` on one copy and `count_word` on the other.

Also, take a precaution not to output the count for the same word twice.

```
int count_word(char * mot, char * text, int offset) {
  int n = 0;
  char *p;

  p = strstr(text, mot);
  assert(p != NULL);
  if (p - text < offset)
      return -1; // if the word was found at an earlier offset, return an error code 

  while (p != NULL) {
    n++;
    p = strstr(p + 1, mot);
  }  

  return n;
}

void show_all_words(char * text) {
    char *text_rw = strdup(text); // make a read-write copy to use with strtok
    char * p = strtok(text_rw, " .,;-!?");

    while (p != NULL) {
      int offset = p - text; // offset of the word inside input text
      int count = count_word(p, text, offset);
      if (count != -1) // -1 is an error code that says "already looked at that word"
          printf ("%s : %d\n", p, count );
      p = strtok(NULL, " .,;-!?");
    }
    free(text_rw); // delete the copy
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the approach.
You could use an array to store the index of first appearance of each word and the count of appearance.
Only one travel in string but more travels in auxiliary array to check if the current word was already counted.

I hope is useful for you.

Comment: As your string gets large recounting for each word will be way expensive. You want to count everything once, and then report it. Best would be put all the tokens into an array, then sort the array alphabetically and then count.